# Thread creation in C

Tags: c, pthreads

Can somebody please explain why the following loop for thread creation fails without the sleep function call?

```
   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++) {
      printf("Main: creating thread %d\n", t);
      rc = pthread_create(&thread[t], NULL, BusyWork, (void *)&t); 
      sleep(1);
      if (rc) {
         perror("pthread_create");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }
      }
```

If sleep is not inserted then thread function seems to take as an argument
an arbitrary integer between 0 ad NUM_THREADS.

I'm running this on an Ubuntu machine.

Comment: You're passing a pointer to `t`, which is a race condition for anything using that pointer. The sleep fixes it because presumably your thread function (not shown) uses that value before `t` is modified by the loop due to sleeping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are passing `t` as a pointer, then change `t` after creating the thread. So each thread refers to the same variable. Which also is a great candidate for race condition bugs. Simply don't do that.

Instead create a hard copy per thread:

```
type* tmp = malloc(sizeof(t));
memcpy(tmp, &t, sizeof(t));
pthread_create(&thread[t], NULL, BusyWork, tmp);
...

void* BusyWork (void* arg)
{
  ...
  free(arg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing *the same* pointer to each thread, but still expecting each to see different values, which is not how things work.

I don't think it's a good idea to let the main program end without doing anything to collect/join the threads back together, either.

Comment: "the t variable goes out of scope before the threads start to run"  No. They are simply passing the variable by reference and then expect it not to change for some reason. Hence "thread function seems to take as an argument an arbitrary integer between 0 ad NUM_THREADS". If the variable had gone out of scope the value would either be `NUM_THREADS - 1` or some complete garbage.

Comment: Either way, `t`'s scope is irrelevant.

Comment: @Lundin Okay fine, I rewrote it to put more emphasis on the same-variable thing. Thanks.